# How to install pip for a specific python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have my deployment system running CentOS 6.

It has by default python 2.6.6 installed. So, "which python" gives me /usr/bin/python (which is 2.6.6)

I later installed python3.5, which is invoked as python3 ("which python3" gives me /usr/local/bin/python3)

Using pip, I need to install a few packages that are specific to python3. So I did pip install using:-
"sudo yum install python-pip"
So "which pip" is /usr/bin/pip.

Now whenever I do any "pip install", it just installs it for 2.6.6. :-(

It is clear that pip installation got tied to python 2.6.6 and invoking pip later, only installs packages for 2.6.6.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: Check if you have a program `pip3` installed. This downloads python3 versions of packages.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Each `pip` is tied to its Python binary. So installation packages using one pip instance will not install packages for other Python versions.

Comment: How did you your install python3.5?

Comment: I disagree it is a duplicate. A new version of python has installed. This version does not have a pip yet. In the possible duplicate pip for the new python version is assumed to be installed.

Answer (score 17):

If `pip` isn’t already installed, then first try to bootstrap it from the standard library:

```
$ python3.5 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

If that still doesn’t allow you to run pip:

- Securely Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
- Run `sudo python3.5 get-pip.py`.

Now you can use `pip3` to install packages for python3.5. For example, try:

```
$ sudo pip3 install ipython  # isntall IPython for python3.5
```

Alternatively, as long as the corresponding `pip` has been installed, you can use `pip` for a specific Python version like this:

```
$ python3.5 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.5
```

---

References:

- [Ensure you can run pip from the command line](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line)
- [work with multiple versions of Python installed in parallel?](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

Comment: you may need to add `sudo` before `python3.5 -m ensurepip --default-pip  `

Answer (score 2):

I have python 3.6 and 3.8 on my Ubuntu 18.04 WSL machine. Running

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

`pip3 install my_package_name`

kept installing packages into Python 3.6 dist directories. The only way that I could install packages for Python 3.8 was:

`python3.8 -m pip install my_package_name`

That installed appropriate package into the Python 3.8 dist package directory so that when I ran my code with python3.8, the required package was available.

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to install `pip` for a specific python version

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
/opt/local/bin/python2.7 get-pip.py
```

Script is from official doc: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score -3):

On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I wanted to install pip for my second python version (python3) and the following command did the trick for me:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: In my case, this was not helpful since it still downloaded python3.6 even though I already had 3.7 installed.